# Tablesorter not loading in Django

Tags: jquery, django, tablesorter

Tablesorter doesn’t work for my Django-based website.  Clicking on the table header doesn’t do anything, and I didn’t see any error message either.  The console error message for jquery.tablesorter displays only:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    jquery.tablesorter.js:1
```

I feel like something simple was missing…
The JS plugins were invoked with:

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>…</thead>
<tbody>…</tbody>
…
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]});
    }
);
</script>
```

The JS files are in a static folder with the following structure:

```
myvenv
mysite
    |---- db.sqlite3
    |---- manage.py
    |---- blog
            |---- management
            |---- migrations
            |---- templates
            |---- templatetags
            |---- admin.py
            |---- models.py
            |---- urls.py
            |---- views.py
    |---- static
            |---- js
                  |---- jquery.js
                  |---- jquery.tablesorter.js
                  |---- …
    |---- mysite
```

Comment: is `js/jquery.tablesorter.js` getting loaded in your browser?

Comment: From the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    jquery.tablesorter.js:1

Comment: That was after removing all html comment

Comment: Can you edit your questions with above details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, I need to specify the path for STATICFILES_DIRS when testing locally, everything is working fine now